# GUI Program Crashes Outside Netbeans But Fine Inside

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

So this is a relatively basic program that contacts an FTP server, and makes a log of the files present. It uses a GUI to boot and start the process. However, outside of Netbeans (as a standalone .jar or in Eclipse) it crashes once the start button is pressed (inner Class Start). I can't understand why this is happening so any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
public class GUI {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel jPanel;
private FTPSearch demo;

public GUI() {
    initialise();

}

public void initialise() {
    //set nimbus look and feel
    try {
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    frame = new JFrame();
    jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    JButton jButton = new JButton("Start");
    jButton.addActionListener(new Start());
    jPanel.add(jButton);
    frame.setContentPane(jPanel);
    frame.setTitle("FTP Communicator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    demo = new FTPSearch();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        try {
            GUI window = new GUI();
            window.frame.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

class Start implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {

                demo.searchAndLog();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
}

}
```

Then the FTP class:

```
public class FTPSearch {

String server;
int port;
String user;
String password;
FTPClient Client;

public FTPSearch() {
    server = "ftp.pagesuite.com";
    port = 21;
    user = "tim";
    password = "access28";
    Client = new FTPClient();
}

public void searchAndLog() {
    try {

        Client.connect(server, port);

        int reply = Client.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            System.out.println("Connect fail");
            return;
        }

        boolean ableToConnect = Client.login(user, password);

        if (!ableToConnect) {
            System.out.println("Login Fail");
            return;
        }

        String[] files2 = Client.listNames();
        //String dir2 = ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory();
        //System.out.println("directory is: " + dir2);
        printNames(files2);
        logNames(files2);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            if (Client.isConnected()) {
                Client.logout();
                Client.disconnect();
                System.out.println("logged out");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void printNames(String files[]) {
    if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
        for (String aFile : files) {
            System.out.println(aFile);
        }
    }
}

private static void logNames(String files[]) {
    if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
        for (String aFile : files) {
            writeToLog(aFile);
        }
    }
}

private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
    String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
    if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
        for (String reply : replies) {
            System.out.println("SERVER: " + reply);
        }
    }
}

public static void writeToLog(String log) {
    File f = new File("LogFile.txt");
    boolean exists = f.exists();

    if (!exists) {
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    FileWriter fWriter;

    try {
        fWriter = new FileWriter(f, true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        out.write(log + "\n");
        out.newLine();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
 }
```

So here is where it seems to fail:

```
        System.out.println("attempt to retrieve names");
        String[] files2 = Client.listNames();
        System.out.println("names retrieved");
```

It will print the first statement, but never reach the second print. It must be failing on the second line of code, not sure why..

Comment: What does the stack trace reveal? Run the Jar from the command line to get the output. If you cannot figure it out from that, copy the entire trace and post it here as an [edit] to the question. It's time for some basic debugging, which you should have done **before** posting a question to SO.

Comment: ok so it runs from the CMD, although it doesn't write to the log file. It prints the output to the command window though. Still doesn't run under other circumstances and doesn't provide any error messages just freezes up to the point where have to use task manager to stop it.

Comment: You should add more system out along the way to get more information and get back to us. By example right after the connect method and juste before the list method

Comment: System.out.println("attempt to retrieve names");
            String[] files2 = Client.listNames();
            System.out.println("names retrieved");  

It prints the first line but doesn't ever reach the second call for println so it must be having an issue with the second line of code where it makes an array. Unsure why/

Comment: Please help still no luck have tried everything...

Comment: *"Please help .."* Tip: Add @XavierBouclet (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.